# Force Windows to treat USB drive as internal

Tags: windows, windows-8, usb, dynamic-disk

How do you force Windows Pro to enable dynamic disk mode on an external USB drive? I have a small home server using a NUC and multi drive USB enclosure that I'd like to be able to use dynamic disks with. Currently it went let me enable dynamic disks on those drives.

Comment: Why would an **internal** drive use USB, when SATA is much faster?

Comment: This isn't really an internal drive. The computer, an Intel NUC, is the size of a sandwich with no internal space for full size drives. I'm wanting to connect an external drive enclosure that supports four full size hard drives.